# How to fill least occupied first after calculating total permutations (Not Homework)

Tags: java, arrays, permutation

**The question is "Can you consider the following perms / combs problem and write something in Javascript to provide a solution for given inputs: Soldiers on returning home choose to sleep in the least occupied barracks or, where multiple barracks are joint-least occupied, at random from among those. Write function that takes as inputs S, the number of soldiers, and B, the number of barracks, and returns the number of possible sleeping arrangements."

I have found the total permutations possible. For e.g for 3 soldiers and 2 barracks the total arrangements possible are 6. However, the question requires me to only include soldiers in least occupied barrack so the correct answer is 4. I am not sure how to reflect that in my code. I assume i would use an IF function but I don't know if that is correct or how to use the correct syntax here. I would greatly appreciate any help!!**

This is the code I wrote to calculate total permutations

```
import java.util.Random;   

public class Main {

/**
 * @param S The number of soldiers
 * @param B The number of barracks
 * @return Number of possible sleeping arrangements
 */
static public long PossibleArrangements(int S, int B) {
    /**
     * The number of possible sleeping arrangements will be
     * (https://imgur.com/gallery/Jrb9UUB)
     * 
     * It is assumed the answer lies in a 64 bit integer, otherwise we will have to take modulo
     */
    
    // No arrangments for 0 barracks
    if(B==0)return 0;

    // precompute the factorial array
    int n = Math.max(S, B);
    long []fact = new long[n+1]; 
    fact[0]=1;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        fact[i]=fact[i-1]*i;
    }

    // calculate result
    long result=1;
    result*=fact[S];
    result*=fact[B];

    for(int i=0;i<B;i++){
        int add=0;
        if(S%B > i)add=1;
        result/=fact[S/B+add];
    }

    return result;
}


/** 
 * @return A random integer between 1 to 10
 */
static public int getRandomNumber(){
    Random random = new Random();
    return random.nextInt(10)+1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    /**
     * There will only be two arrangements possible for 2 soldiers and 2 barracks
     */
    System.out.println(PossibleArrangements(2,2));
    /**
     * There will be 6 arrangements possible for 3 soldiers and 2 barracks
     * 
     *  S1->B1 , S2->B1 , S3->B2
     *  S1->B1 , S2->B2 , S3->B1
     *  S1->B2 , S2->B1 , S3->B1
     *  S1->B2 , S2->B2 , S3->B1
     *  S1->B2 , S2->B1 , S3->B2
     *  S1->B1 , S2->B2 , S3->B2
     */
    System.out.println(PossibleArrangements(3,2));

    /**
     * Possible arrangements for random number of Soldiers and Barracks
     */
    System.out.println(PossibleArrangements(getRandomNumber(),getRandomNumber()));
}

}
```

Comment: does `least occupied barracks` actually mean that `max-min<=1`? if so, we need distribute soldiers equally across  barracks and them distribute the rest.

Comment: Yes, I think so! As long as we equally divide soldiers across barracks it fills the least occupied condition. I'm guessing i could say something like if count of barrack 1 > count of barrack 2 -> add to barrack 2 but i don't know to do that for n number of soldiers and barracks

Comment: Just noting that the example code provided here is in Java, not JavaScript. @TalhaBinFahim, you might more of the right eyes on this question if you edit it to replace the "Javascript" tag with "Java".

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to get result programmatically (via simulation), or you just need a result?

My idea:

- Let `s=k*b + r`, then the amount of `equal` permutations would be `s!/((k!^b)*r!)`, the logic is:

  - there are `s` options to select 1st soldier for the 1st barrack, `s-1` options to select 2nd soldier for the 1st barrack (or 1st soldier for the 2nd barrack), and `s*(s-1)*...*(r+1)` options in total, which is `s!/r!`
  - now there are `k` soldiers in each barrack and we need to rid off duplicate permutations, so we divide by `(k!^b)`
  - alternatively: `comb(s,k)` options to populate 1st barrack, `comb(s-k,k)` options to populate 2nd barrack, etc
- now we need to multiply it on `b!/(b-r)!`, because: 1st of the remaining soldiers has `b` options to select barrack, 2nd - `b-1`, etc: `b*(b-1)*...*(b-r+1)=b!/(b-r)!`
- and finally we need to divide by `(k+1)^r`: we got `(k+1)` duplicate permutations in `r` barracks.

final formula:

`s!b!/((k!^b)*r!*(b-r)!*((k+1)^r))`

Comment: Thank you so much Andrey! I need the result in a coding language (preferably java) but this is really helpful as well. To clarify, is R the total number of barracks and B the remainder of barracks (for e.g if there is 2 soldiers and three barracks the remaining barrack is b= (3-2) = 1

Comment: Also, I might be understanding the equation wrong but if I do the calculation for 3 soldiers and 2 barracks, I get an answer of 10 something when I should be getting 4. I follow the logic behind the equation which makes me think that the problem is with my understanding of what s, k , b and r represent so if you could kindly elaborate on that, I would be really grateful.

Comment: `s` - amount of soldiers, `b` - amount of barracks, `k` - quotient, `r` - remainder